# Ignore null fields when DEserializing JSON with Gson or Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, deserialization

I know there's lots of questions about skipping fields with a null value when serializing objects to JSON. 
I want to skip / ignore fields with null values when deserializing JSON to an object.

Consider the class

```
public class User {
    Long id = 42L;
    String name = "John";
}
```

and the JSON string

```
{"id":1,"name":null}
```

When doing

```
User user = gson.fromJson(json, User.class)
```

I want  `user.id` to be '1' and `user.name` to be 'John'.

Is this possible with either Gson or Jackson in a general fashion (without special `TypeAdapter`s or similar)?

Comment: How will user.name be 'John'. if the example json has  "name":null ? Are you asking if it can skip Null values in Json and not override the default in the class?

Comment: @jeffporter Yes that's exactly the question.

Comment: Did you find a pretty solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem as well

Comment: Now it is 2019 )) Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 6):

A lot of time gone by, but if you like me ran into this question and you are using at least Jackson 2.9 then one way you could sovle it is using [JsonSetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html) and [Nulls.SKIP](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/Nulls.html#SKIP):

```
public class User {
    private Long id = 42L;
    
    @JsonSetter(Nulls.SKIP)
    private String name = "John";

    ... cooresponding getters and setters  
   
}
```

This way, when null is encountered, setter will not be called.

Note: more details can be found [here](https://cowtowncoder.medium.com/jackson-2-9-features-b2a19029e9ff).

Comment: This code actually does not compile. The JsonSetter line must be `@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.SKIP)`

Comment: In order to skip null values in collections, you could use `@JsonSetter(contentNulls = Nulls.SKIP)`

Answer (score 2):

What I did in my case is to set a default value on the getter:

```
public class User {
    private Long id = 42L;
    private String name = "John";

    public getName(){
       //You can check other conditions
       return name == null? "John" : name;
    }
}
```

I guess this will be a pain for many fields but it works in the simple case of less number of fields.

Answer (score -1):

To skip using TypeAdapters, I'd make the POJO do a null check when the setter method is called.

Or look at

```
@JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL)
```

The annotation needs to be at Class level, not method level.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) //or Include.NON_EMPTY, if that fits your use case 
public static class RequestPojo {
    ...
}
```

For Deserialise you can use following at class level.

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

Comment: @JsonInclude(value = Include.NON_NULL) seems to be only working when serializing, not when deserializing.

Answer (score -1):

Albeit not the most concise solution, with Jackson you can handle setting the properties yourself with a custom `@JsonCreator`:

```
public class User {
    Long id = 42L;
    String name = "John";

    @JsonCreator
    static User ofNullablesAsOptionals(
            @JsonProperty("id") Long id,
            @JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        User user = new User();
        if (id != null) user.id = id;
        if (name != null) user.name = name;
        return user;
    }
}
```